# plot data to their respective rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There is a collection of data which needs to be shown in the spreadsheet. I mean data will have values for
each row(in this case Row 1, Row 2 etc). I need to show them in the spreadsheet. How could i show 
those data to their respective row name. I could only find the range up to where data will be plotted.

Here is how i have done

```
function plotData() {
 var data = [
  {
    "Row1": "Row1 Data",
    "Row7": 5,
    "WillNotBeInOther": 0.75
  },
  {
    "Row2": 5000,
    "Row3": 0,
    "Row4": 5000,
    "Row5": null,
    "Row6": 5,
    "Row7": null,
    "Row8": 0.25,
    "Row9": 0,
    "Row10": 0
  },
  {
    "Row2": 6000,
    "Row3": 20000,
    "Row4": 26000,
    "Row5": null,
    "Row6": null,
    "Row7": null,
    "Row8": null,
    "Row9": 0,
    "Row10": 0
  },
  {
    "Row2": 7000,
    "Row3": 1000,
    "Row4": 8000,
    "Row5": null,
    "Row6": null,
    "Row7": null,
    "Row8": null,
    "Row9": 0,
    "Row10": 0
  }
]

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "PlotData";
  var sheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var startRow = 4;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var plottableSheetRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 3, lastRow-startRow+1, data.length);
  plottableSheetRange.setValue(10)
}
```

Here is the spreadsheet where I am working on

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tLNZv4F4lpBAnmHN5H0pBiirW4MVIfTexll9jPA03hI/edit#gid=0

code.gs is the script.

It should look like this

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tLNZv4F4lpBAnmHN5H0pBiirW4MVIfTexll9jPA03hI/edit#gid=1869973739

Comment: It seems that the script of your shared Spreadsheet is different from that of your question. Which script should we use? And also can you provide the output you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike sorry i have updated the script with the data. I have listed sample sheet as well.

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating the shared Spreadsheet. When I saw the output sheet you expect, I thought that the index of the array of `data` might be corresponding to the column number. But at the first index of `data`, it seems that `"Row7": 5` and `"WillNotBeInOther": 0.75` of `{"Row1": "Row1 Data", "Row7": 5, "WillNotBeInOther": 0.75},` are not used. So can you explain about the logic for converting `data` to the values for putting to Spreadsheet?

Comment: in my case the first object will be always different to remaining object. Thus like in the sample sheet(Output sheet) you have sheen in C column only Row 1 is filled and for column d to f, Row 2 to Row 10 is filled. As first object `{"Row1": "Row1 Data", "Row7": 5, "WillNotBeInOther": 0.75}` has not any other column that is listed in the sheet so other than Row1 others are not filled.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor understanding. About the value of `{"Row1": "Row1 Data", "Row7": 5, "WillNotBeInOther": 0.75}`, `"Row1": "Row1 Data"` is used. But `"Row7": 5` and `"WillNotBeInOther": 0.75` are not used. I cannot understand about the logic for this situation.

Comment: those unused item are required for further math calculation which is not dependent on plotting in the sheet only for math related part for below objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199227/discussion-between-serenity-and-tanaike).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed 2 sample scripts by including your specification. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to achieve from the following object to the image using Google Apps Script.

  - From:

    ```
    var data = [
      {"Row1":"Row1Data","Row7":5,"WillNotBeInOther":0.75},
      {"Row2":5000,"Row3":0,"Row4":5000,"Row5":null,"Row6":5,"Row7":null,"Row8":0.25,"Row9":0,"Row10":0},
      {"Row2":6000,"Row3":20000,"Row4":26000,"Row5":null,"Row6":null,"Row7":null,"Row8":null,"Row9":0,"Row10":0},
      {"Row2":7000,"Row3":1000,"Row4":8000,"Row5":null,"Row6":null,"Row7":null,"Row8":null,"Row9":0,"Row10":0}
    ];
    ```
  - To:

    [image]
- You want to put the values from the cell "B4".
- As your specification of above value, you want to use only the value of `Row1` from `{"Row1":"Row1Data","Row7":5,"WillNotBeInOther":0.75}` at the first index.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

Before you use the following scripts, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). When the all column length of the array is not the same, the method of Spreadsheets.Values.update is easy to put the array to Spreadsheet. So I used Sheets API.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the key names from `Row1` to `Row 10` are also put.

#### Sample script:

```
function plotData() {
  var data = [
    {"Row1":"Row1Data","Row7":5,"WillNotBeInOther":0.75},
    {"Row2":5000,"Row3":0,"Row4":5000,"Row5":null,"Row6":5,"Row7":null,"Row8":0.25,"Row9":0,"Row10":0},
    {"Row2":6000,"Row3":20000,"Row4":26000,"Row5":null,"Row6":null,"Row7":null,"Row8":null,"Row9":0,"Row10":0},
    {"Row2":7000,"Row3":1000,"Row4":8000,"Row5":null,"Row6":null,"Row7":null,"Row8":null,"Row9":0,"Row10":0}
  ];

  // Convert "data" to an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  var values = data.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    if (i === 0) e = {"Row1": e["Row1"]}; // From your replying, the first index is modified for your specification.
    Object.keys(e).forEach(function(f) {
      var n = Number(f.replace("Row", "")) - 1;
      if (!Array.isArray(ar[n])) ar[n] = ["Row " + (n + 1)];
      ar[n][i + 1] = e[f];
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // Put the converted array to Spreadsheet.
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "PlotData";
  var sheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var startRow = 4;
  var range = "'" + sheetname + "'!B" + startRow;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: values}, activeSheet.getId(), range, {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the key names from `Row1` to `Row 10` are not put.

#### Sample script:

```
function plotData() {
  var data = [
    {"Row1":"Row1Data","Row7":5,"WillNotBeInOther":0.75},
    {"Row2":5000,"Row3":0,"Row4":5000,"Row5":null,"Row6":5,"Row7":null,"Row8":0.25,"Row9":0,"Row10":0},
    {"Row2":6000,"Row3":20000,"Row4":26000,"Row5":null,"Row6":null,"Row7":null,"Row8":null,"Row9":0,"Row10":0},
    {"Row2":7000,"Row3":1000,"Row4":8000,"Row5":null,"Row6":null,"Row7":null,"Row8":null,"Row9":0,"Row10":0}
  ];

  // Convert "data" to an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  var values = data.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    if (i === 0) e = {"Row1": e["Row1"]}; // From your replying, the first index is modified for your specification.
    Object.keys(e).forEach(function(f) {
      var n = Number(f.replace("Row", "")) - 1;
      if (!Array.isArray(ar[n])) ar[n] = [];
      ar[n][i] = e[f];
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // Put the converted array to Spreadsheet.
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "PlotData";
  var sheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var startRow = 4;
  var range = "'" + sheetname + "'!C" + startRow;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: values}, activeSheet.getId(), range, {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
}
```

### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: I did not understand `Object.keys(e).forEach(function(f) {` parts. What if the name is like `Share Value`, `Share Percentage` instead of `Row 1`, `Row 2` etc? Just want to get the idea.

Comment: @Serenity Thank you for replying. 1. About `Object.keys(e).forEach(function(f) {`, each key of the object which is an element of the array is retrieved. And the 2 dimensional array is created for putting to Spreadsheet. You can see more information at [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: @Serenity 2. About `What if the name is like Share Value, Share Percentage instead of Row 1, Row 2 etc?`, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot see the vision of your question. And I think that this is new question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. At that time, please close this question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: first of all thanks a lot for your kind effort and helping nature. Sorry for asking a new question. I have made a new question as i did not understand how you mapped the value to corresponding row name. Here is the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870723/how-to-map-values-to-its-corresponding-row-name . Only the name of rows are changed. Can you explain me there, please?

Comment: @Serenity Thank you for replying and your response. I would like to check it.