# how to map values to its corresponding row name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There is a collection of data which needs to be shown in the spreadsheet. I mean data will have values for each row(in this case Housing, CapitalRaised, SizePerSquare etc). How to plot below data in the spreadsheet in following format?

[image]

the data comes in this format

```
[
  {
    "Housing": "Before housing price",
    "Price": 5,
    "Rate": 0.75
  },
  {
    "CapitalRaised": 5000,
    "SizePerSquare": 12,
    "Price": null,
    "RatePerSquare": 1.25
  },
  {
    "CapitalRaised": 6000,
    "SizePerSquare": 24,
    "Price": null,
    "RatePerSquare": 1
  },
  {
    "CapitalRaised": 7000,
    "SizePerSquare": 24,
    "Price": null,
    "RatePerSquare": 0.75,
  }
]
```

Here is the code

```
function plotData() {
  var data =[
    {
        "Housing": "Before Capital Raised",
        "Price": 5,
        "Rate": 0.75
    },
    {
        "CapitalRaised": 5000,
        "SizePerSquare": 12,
        "Price": null,
        "RatePerSquare": 1.25
    },
    {
        "CapitalRaised": 6000,
        "SizePerSquare": 24,
        "Price": null,
        "RatePerSquare": 1
    },
    {
        "AmountRaised": 7000,
        "SizePerSquare": 24,
        "Price": null,
        "RatePerSquare": 0.75,
    }
  ]

  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "PlotData2";
  var sheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var startRow = 4;
  var range = "'" + sheetname + "'!B" + startRow;

}
```

Here is the link to spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tLNZv4F4lpBAnmHN5H0pBiirW4MVIfTexll9jPA03hI/edit#gid=1286090443

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to achieve the following situation using Google Apps Script.

  - From:

    ```
    var data = [
      {"Housing":"Before housing price","Price":5,"Rate":0.75},
      {"CapitalRaised":5000,"SizePerSquare":12,"Price":null,"RatePerSquare":1.25},
      {"CapitalRaised":6000,"SizePerSquare":24,"Price":null,"RatePerSquare":1},
      {"CapitalRaised":7000,"SizePerSquare":24,"Price":null,"RatePerSquare":0.75}
    ];
    ```
  - To:

    [image]
- The header titles of rows are constant.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? In this answer, from your question, I thought that the header titles of rows are constant. I used this situation.

#### Sample script:

Before you use the following scripts, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). When the all column length of the array is not the same, the method of Spreadsheets.Values.update is easy to put the array to Spreadsheet. So I used Sheets API.

```
function plotData() {
  var data = [
    {"Housing":"Before housing price","Price":5,"Rate":0.75},
    {"CapitalRaised":5000,"SizePerSquare":12,"Price":null,"RatePerSquare":1.25},
    {"CapitalRaised":6000,"SizePerSquare":24,"Price":null,"RatePerSquare":1},
    {"CapitalRaised":7000,"SizePerSquare":24,"Price":null,"RatePerSquare":0.75}
  ];

  // Convert "data" to an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  var rowHeaders = ["Housing", "Price", "CapitalRaised", "RatePerSquare", "SizePerSquare"];
  var values = data.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    rowHeaders.forEach(function(g, n) {
      if (!Array.isArray(ar[n])) ar[n] = [g];
      ar[n][i + 1] = e[g];
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // Put the converted array to Spreadsheet.
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "PlotData2";
  var sheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var startRow = 4;
  var range = "'" + sheetname + "'!B" + startRow;
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: values}, activeSheet.getId(), range, {valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"});
}
```

- In above script, if there are the keys, which are not included in `rowHeaders`, in the keys of object of `data`, the values of the keys are not used. Please be careful this.

  - For example, `Rate` of the first element of `data` is not used.

#### Note:

- In your data, it seems that the data of `the data comes in this format` is different from the data of `Here is the code`. `"CapitalRaised": 7000`, and `"AmountRaised": 7000` are different. From your image of the expected result, I supposed that you want to use the data of `the data comes in this format`. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: this is what I was expecting. I was confused in data.reduce part which is now clear. Thanks a lot for your kind effort and helping nature, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Serenity Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I used `reduce()` used because the array and object can be used by initializing and the process cost of `reduce()` is lower than that of the for loop at Google Apps Script. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/848aeafaac1ec676900bb78e3ce220b6)

Comment: I understood the reduce part after comparing two codes but will look much more in deeper as I did not know about process cost  before. Thanks got to know a lot from you.